# Full-width nested list inside another with table display

Tags: html, css

I have a list that is rendered using JS components, in a way that doesn't allow for much flexibility in terms of structure. The CSS on the other hand, I can tweak to my liking.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
ul,
table {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li,
tr {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
li > div,
td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}
.right {
  padding-left: 60px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- My structure -->

<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="right">Cell 1.1</div>
    <div>Cell 1.2</div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Nested cell 1</li>
        <li>Nested cell 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="right">Cell 2.1</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<!-- Ideal representation -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Cell 1.1</td>
    <td>Cell 1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Nested cell 1</td>
          <td>Nested cell 2</td>
          <tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">Cell 2.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hfxzjwL/) for anyone who prefers it.

I need two things, essentially:

- Make the width of the first column ("Cell 1.1", "Cell 2.1", etc) adjust automatically and grow to fit the widest content of any row (hence table display)
- When any of the items / rows have a nested list inside them, display  them **below** the parent list, in full-width / full-colspan (i.e. between rows 1 and 2)

The CSS I have now is my best attempt. I started with block layout, but never could achieve a fluid first column that adapted to the entire columns width. I did achieve that first goal with the CSS in the snippet, but now my nested list is displayed as a normal cell as is constrained in a column.

The snippet has two scenarios: the top one is the incomplete scenario I currently have, the other is the visual result I want, but with a structure I can't have at the moment.

Is there a way to achieve the two goals above without changing the HTML structure and without resorting to JS?

Comment: ad width: auto; to your ul tag in CSS to fix problem 1
and it will be easier if you provide a JSfidle

Comment: That wouldn't really solve problem 1... The ul grows automatically, but then the two columns inside of it grow at different rates depending on the content they have. I want them to grow in a synchronised way. Also, I updated the question with a JSFiddle link in case you want to give it a go.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it can completely be done in CSS, but I think your best bet would be using Flexbox properties. You could use `order` and `flex-direction` properties to "position" cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprisingly, the solution was closer to my ideal representation than what I was originally going for. Note to self: if I want table-like behaviour for displaying tabular data, maybe regular tables are not a bad idea...

Anyway, the problem arose from the fact that I use VueJS components, and they can only have one root element in their templates. In my mind that root element was either a `tr` or a `li`, because they represented rows of my tabular data. That meant I was in a dead-end, because I needed multiple `tr` if using a table, or if I nested `ul` inside my `li`, the nested list would display inside a single cell and could never take the full width of the table.

The solution was to use `tbody` as my component's root element. This meant I could respect Vue's requirement of having just one root element and put many `tr` inside it. Visually, it's just the same as having multiple `tr`. **Column width is also adjusted to fit content throughout rows, even though `tr` elements are not direct siblings.** And it also has the benefit of being valid HTML.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
tr {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.right {
  padding-left: 60px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">Cell 1.1</td>
      <td>Cell 1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Nested cell 1</td>
            <td>Nested cell 2</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">Cell 2.1</td>
      <td>Cell 2.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're after, don't expect it to be pretty since this is a slaughter of HTML / CSS, the HTML is unchanged (did not even add any classes).

https://jsfiddle.net/9hfxzjwL/5/

For the raw upated css:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li div:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #6da5ff;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

ul li div:nth-child(3) {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li div ul {
  width: 100%;
}

ul li div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  background: #6da5ff;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px;
}

li + li {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Good effort! But it only works if I know beforehand the structure of the tables and the nested tables. The examples are a simplification of the actual structure, which contains a lot more cells and rows and can, in theory at least, be infinitely nested.

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood your requirements, is there no way for you to modify the structure of this? It seems that your problems is inherently coming from the way the data is structured in the html

Comment: Well, I *can* but I didn't want to. I'm using stand-alone Vue 2 components, which only allow for one root HTML element in their templates, which means I can only generate one `li` per item (which may or may not contain nested items) and not the two I would require for proper formatting.